# Checking if this is a Stack/DFS

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some work that involves grabbing some specific nodes in a tree-like structure. My colleague claims that my implementation, which we are trying to use a stack and a DFS algorithm, is not that.

Here is my implementation of using a stack to create a basic DFS algorithm:

```
const findMatchingElements = (node, name, result) => {
  for(const child of node.children) {
    findMatchingElements(child, name, result)
  }
  if(node.name === name) result.push(node)
  return result
}

const getElements = (tree, name) => {
  return findMatchingElements(tree, name, [])
}

getElements(obj, 'foo')
```

And a sample input:

```
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'foo',
  children: [
    {
      id: 45,
      name: 'bar',
      children: [
        {
          id: 859,
          name: 'bar',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 67,
      name: 'foo',
      children: [
        {
          id: 456,
          name: 'bar',
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: 653,
          name: 'foo',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting my expected output:

```
 [ { id: 653, name: 'foo', children: [] },
  { id: 67, name: 'foo', children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { id: 1, name: 'foo', children: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

In the order I expect as well, but my colleague for some reason does not think this is a proper stack implementation. Am I missing something? Is it because of the way the final answer is printed out? To me, this feels like it is a stack.

Comment: What does he say when you ask him why?  What reasoning does he give to say that this is not what you say it is?

Comment: @zero298 see the accepted answer to see what ended up being the "problem", as it were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the order of the lines in your recursive function, you are using a post-order traversal in your DFS. In your implementation, there's no such thing as in-order. Your co-worker might have been expecting pre-order DFS. To convert your algorithm to pre-order, just check the node before visiting the children nodes.

```
const findMatchingElements = (node, name, result) => {
  if(node.name === name) result.push(node)
  for(const child of node.children) {
    findMatchingElements(child, name, result)
  }
  return result
}
```

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search_2)

Comment: I think this is what he was getting at, because once I modified my function and showed him the output, it was in line with what he was expected. Appears that he wasn't conveying what kind of traversal to use.

Comment: He also mentioned that he was concerned about using this function on a tree of unknown depth, but I'm not sure what the problem there would be.

Comment: The problem can be reaching maximum call stack limit

Comment: Any way to curtail that @Aleksey? I don't think there's any memoization we can do.

Comment: You can replace recursion with loop and use your own stack to keep unprocessed nodes

Comment: @Aleksey Ah, so something like adding the root to the stack, pop it, then check if it matches the name parameter. If it does, then add it to the resulting array. Then, we'd still use a for...of loop to add all the current node's children to the stack. Rinse and repeat until the stack is empty!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about what you're disagreeing about here but that output looks like a stack to me if you agree that it's LIFO once the client starts using it.
Right now it's just a JavaScript array, but if you start pushing and popping on it, and only doing that, then it's a JavaScript implementation of a stack.

Answer (score 0):

You are using stack implicitly via recursion. I guess your colleague means your implementation does not use stack explicitly without recursion.

Comment: See accepted answer. It turned out it was the *type* of DFS he was looking for that was causing the hangup.